# How do I make java's ImageBuffer to read a PNG file correctly?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, resize, crop

For some reason, opening up some PNG files using ImageBuffer and ImageIO does not work. Here's some code I am using that works fine for resizing/cropping JPGs:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(location));

BufferedImage croppedImage = image.getSubimage(
    cropInfo.getX(), cropInfo.getY(), cropInfo.getW(), cropInfo.getH());

BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(
    TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, croppedImage.getType());
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(croppedImage, 0, 0, TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();

this.changeContentType("image/png", ".png"); // not really relevant. just a property

ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "png", new File(location));

return resizedImage;
```

The goal of this function is to take whatever type is given, resize and crop the image, and then save it to PNG with the same filename.

It works on Windows, but if I crop/resize on Linux (lenny), it crashes altogether and complains about the type of the file (it says the type is 0).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:490)
    trainingdividend.domain.file.ServerImage.resizeImage(ServerImage.java:68)
    trainingdividend.domain.file.ServerImage.cropAndResize(ServerImage.java:80)
    trainingdividend.service.user.UserAccountManagerImpl.cropAvatar(UserAccountManagerImpl.java:155)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Solutions?

Is there another library I can use altogether?

Comment: Which JVM are you using in Linux? (Edit: judging by the `sun.reflect` in the stack trace, it's Sun's, but just to be sure)

Comment: Yes, the latest sun jvm. 1.6_24

Comment: Well I fixed it. I put a hack in there where if the image.getType() == 0, I manually set it to 5. This works.

Comment: FWIW, I just got done compiling your code on windows (jvm 1.6.0_20) and it worked perfectly on a random jpg. I wonder if it could have been your input file.

Comment: Nope, this code works on windows for everything. It just didn't work on Debian (lenny) with an upgraded jdk. I just check to see if the type is 0, and if it is, I pass in 5. That seems to make it work. My guess is that this is a bug and has nothing to do with me at all :(

Comment: Certainly looks whacky. Googling for that exception gives tons of results in the past 5 years!

Answer (score 7):

When running my function on Windows, croppedImaged.getType() returns the value 5. So, the simple "hack" is to store the type, check to see if it's 0... and if it is, set the value to 5 manually.

```
int imageType = croppedImage.getType();
if(imageType == 0) imageType = 5;
```

We then pass in **imageType** instead and it should work on Linux.

I am sure this has the drawback that if the value is 0 in other cases, it will set it to 5 and that will be wrong. However, this seems to work for common image types on Linux and it hasn't caused any problems.

It's pretty clear that the Windows version of Java 1.6 is perfectly fine, but the Linux version has a bug in it.

Comment: More than 10 years later and I just came across the same weird problem: My code (reads TIF files with the "TwelveMonkeys" library) works fine on my Win 10 PC and `bufferedImage.getType()` prints "5" for all tested images but on a second Win 10 PC the same code throws the `Unknown image type 0` exception for the same images. The only difference is the Java version the PCs are using, mine has 1.8.0_321, while the other PC uses 1.8.0_221. Setting the type manually works on the second PC, no more exception.

Answer (score 1):

egervari, you can use a library like [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) (Apache 2) to do all the resizing for you "properly" that fixes issues like these with a [very simple API](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr/Scalr.html) -- it won't help with the cropping, but the resizing is what it does best (different speeds, qualities, even anti-aliasing if you want).

I would point out that the code you are using now (forcing a CUSTOM type into a 3BYTE_BGR type) should also account for inbound images with an alpha channel.

Also if you want to keep using your custom code, RGB and ARGB are two of the best supported image types in Java2D -- if you use a poorly supported image type, when Java2D goes to perform the image op, it falls back to its software rendering pipeline and doesn't use the specialized hardware accelerated ones. This doesn't just effect performance as you'll see the result actually look worse (e.g. in GIF You see this a lot).

Again, imgscalr takes care of all this for you automatically if you wanted to give it a try, but if not, I figured I'd just give a heads up incase you were running into some of these headaches.

java image processing is... temperamental :)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution would be to convert the file to jpeg first, and then process it. The type 0 bug seems to mostly affect PNG images.