# How to make a java interface that can open an image file and save it to database and resize it?

Tags: database, image, jdbc, db2, save

Say I have a code like this:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class InsertImg2Dbase extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        JButton open = new JButton("Open image to save...");
        private Connection con;

        public void getConnection(){
            try{
                if(con==null){
                    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50001/sample","username","password");
                }
            }catch (SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(source==open){
              // this is where the event when opening the file to be saved will be coded  
            }
        }

        public InsertImg2Dbase(){
            ActionListener al = new InsertImg2Dbase();
            open.setBounds(20, 20, 175, 25);
            open.addActionListener(al);
            add(open);
        }

        public void properties(){
            setLayout(null);
            setTitle("Open Image To Save");
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(220,90);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            InsertImg2Dbase ins = new InsertImg2Dbase();
            ins.properties();
        }    
    }
```

What should I add in the code so the JButton will open an explorer to open an image file(such as jpeg, png, gif, bmp) which will be saved to my database (say my tablename is: "images") as a blob file. And can I add a function which will resize my image let's say for a dimension of 300x650 before being saved to my database?

I would welcome any kind help, I'm still in the learning process and if you could just guide me, I am more than grateful. Any help would be welcomed! Thank you

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836128/how-do-i-make-javas-imagebuffer-to-read-a-png-file-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could incorporate an external tool inside DB2 in order to extend the basic functionality and add support to specific things, like in your case images. For this, you need ImageMagik, then you create some external stored procedures and that's is.

A very good tutorial about this is here in DeveloperWorks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0504stolze/

Once you have done that, you can call db2 procedures that manipulates the stored image before retrieve to the application.