# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0 -- Using PyramidIO

Tags: java

I'm trying to use PyramidIO https://github.com/NIST-ISG/pyramidio/releases to create a DZI file for JavaScript OpenSeaDragon.

I'm getting an "Unknown image type 0" error that's confusing me. It's coming from buildPyramid() in the code below. What I'm doing here is reading in a tiff image with OpenCV, converting it to a BufferedImage, and writing that image so PyramidIO can pick it up and create the DZI. buildPyramid() starts creating the files it's supposed to create, but then this error appears. Any ideas about this? Thanks.

```
@Controller
public class ImageController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String image(Model model) throws IOException {
        File outputFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\workspace\\J2\\util");
        File imageFile = new File("C:\\ML\\prostate_x100_trained\\x100\\B\\bprostate11-100x.tif");
        File outImageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\workspace\\J2\\util\\outImage.png");
        Mat matImage = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\ML\\prostate_x100_trained\\x100\\B\\bprostate11-100x.tif");
        BufferedImage bufImage = PathUtilities.ImageUtils.toBufferedImage(matImage); 
        ImageIO.write(bufImage, "png", outImageFile);

        ScalablePyramidBuilder spb = new ScalablePyramidBuilder(400, 2, "png", "dzi");
        FilesArchiver archiver = new DirectoryArchiver(outputFolder);
        PartialImageReader pir = new BufferedImageReader(imageFile);
        spb.buildPyramid(pir, "pyramidName", archiver, 1);

        model.addAttribute("message", "Test Message from controller.");
        return "image"; 
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace and output that has me confused.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)

2015-11-28 22:43:28.476  INFO 10528 --- [           main] com.J2.J2Application                     : Starting J2Application on ThinkPad-W8 with PID 10528 (C:\Users\Benjamin\workspace\J2\bin started by Benjamin in C:\Users\Benjamin\workspace\J2)
2015-11-28 22:43:28.490  INFO 10528 --- [           main] com.J2.J2Application                     : No profiles are active
2015-11-28 22:43:29.675  INFO 10528 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@795509d9: startup date [Sat Nov 28 22:43:29 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-28 22:43:32.388  INFO 10528 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-11-28 22:43:34.756  INFO 10528 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-11-28 22:43:34.802  INFO 10528 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-11-28 22:43:34.806  INFO 10528 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-11-28 22:43:35.279  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-11-28 22:43:35.291  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5628 ms
2015-11-28 22:43:36.726  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-11-28 22:43:36.746  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-28 22:43:36.748  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-28 22:43:36.749  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-28 22:43:36.749  INFO 10528 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2015-11-28 22:43:38.853  INFO 10528 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@795509d9: startup date [Sat Nov 28 22:43:29 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-28 22:43:39.142  INFO 10528 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.J2.controller.ImageController.image(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.IOException
2015-11-28 22:43:39.150  INFO 10528 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-11-28 22:43:39.152  INFO 10528 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-11-28 22:43:39.331  INFO 10528 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-11-28 22:43:39.389  INFO 10528 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-11-28 22:43:39.648  INFO 10528 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-11-28 22:43:41.744  INFO 10528 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-11-28 22:43:42.175  INFO 10528 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2015-11-28 22:43:42.202  INFO 10528 --- [           main] com.J2.J2Application                     : Started J2Application in 14.895 seconds (JVM running for 19.921)
2015-11-28 22:44:29.878  INFO 10528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-11-28 22:44:29.879  INFO 10528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-11-28 22:44:29.943  INFO 10528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 64 ms
2015-11-28 22:48:57.943 ERROR 10528 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.tools.ImageResizingHelper.resizeImageGraphics2D(ImageResizingHelper.java:78) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.tools.ImageResizingHelper.resizeImage(ImageResizingHelper.java:70) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:194) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:156) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder$TileBuilder.buildTile(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:128) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.ScalablePyramidBuilder.buildPyramid(ScalablePyramidBuilder.java:89) ~[pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar:0.0.3]
    at com.J2.controller.ImageController.image(ImageController.java:38) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Comment: Seems the same issue reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836128/how-do-i-make-javas-imagebuffer-to-read-a-png-file-correctly